# Cambiar formato de fecha

Tags: php, date, datetime

Al convertir este formato de fecha `16:04:52.000 GMT Wed Jul 1 2020` a únicamente obtener esto `01-07-2020`, no obtengo el resultado deseado.

Intente de una forma, pero me esta imprimiendo una fecha que no concuerda con la que yo le mando. Les anexo mi ejemplo.

## Código PHP

```
$fecha_inicio = '16:04:52.000 GMT Wed Jul 1 2020';
$fecha = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($fecha_inicio));
```

## Resultado

```
06-30-20
```

¿Saben porque no me concuerda la fecha?
¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: La función `date()` te devuelve la hora de acuerdo a la zona horaria establecida en el servidor. Si estás manejando GMT, deberías usar [`gmdate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.gmdate.php)

Answer (score 3):

La clase `DateTime` tiene el método [`createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php), que te permite construir un nuevo objeto a partir de cualquier formato válido.

En tu caso, creando el formato a partir de la cadena dada: `16:04:52.000 GMT Wed Jul 1 2020` obtendrás el objeto que esperas exactamente.

En el apartado [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) del Manual de PHP, se explica lo que significa cada letra:

El código quedaría así:

```
#Formato según el dato en $fecha_inicio
$mFormat="H:i:s.u \G\M\T D M d Y"; 
$fecha_inicio = '16:04:52.000 GMT Wed Jul 1 2020';
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat($mFormat, $fecha_inicio);
#Prueba del objeto
var_dump($fecha);
```

La salida del `var_dump()` sería:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-07-01 16:04:52.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

A partir de ahí puedes usar el objeto para imprimir la fecha como quieras, por ejemplo:

```
echo $fecha->format('d-m-Y');
```

**Salida:**

```
01-07-2020
```

Comment: tambien debes decirle que estas forzando la funcion  `DateTime::createFromFormat() ` en php al utilizar esto dentro: `\G\M\T` , desconozco que impacto tiene esta implementacion.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez no entiendo qué significa estar *forzando el php al utilizar esto: `\G\M\T`*, ¿podrías explicarlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

tu error esta relacionado a la configuracion del servidor:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

en mi caso yo uso una configuración `GMT` Laragon/Xamp en windows

```
#date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
date_default_timezone_set(America/Panama); // esto me soluciono a mi mis problema de fechas y hora.
```

[Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

por eso cuando yo utilizo `date()` si me da el output esperado:

### Ejemplo con `GMT` por defecto en el servidor

```
<?php
$fecha_inicio = '16:04:52.000 GMT Wed Jul 1 2020';
echo $fecha   = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fecha_inicio));
```

### output:

```
01-07-2020
```

### en tu caso para resolverlo debes usar `gmdate()`

```
<?php
$fecha_inicio = '16:04:52.000 GMT Wed Jul 1 2020';
echo $fecha   = gmdate('d-m-Y', strtotime($fecha_inicio));
```

### Ejemplo: [Link Ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5d92808dabc2a5f50ef65df65c120a47a4670fc)